# How much damage do each of the different Titans deal punching?

Tags: titanfall

How much damage do each of the Titans do with their melee attack both with and without the Big Punch Tier 2 kit?  I have heard anecdotally that the Atlas punch does less than *both* the Stryder and Ogre which seems a bit tilted, but alas I have no real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic damage done by titan punches is ([source](http://titanfall.gamepedia.com/Titans)):

- **Ogre**: 1,875 with 510 knock back
- **Stryder**: 1,125 with 850 knock back
- **Atlas**: 1,000 with 510 knock back

So the lightweight Stryder has more of a punch than the Atlas, but it also gets knocked back further.

To put these numbers into context:

- **Ogre**: 10,500 health
- **Atlas**: 8,000 health
- **Stryder**: 5,500 health

The Big Punch multiplies these stats by about 1.7, but [slows down the punch](http://titanfall.gamepedia.com/Big_Punch).

All 3 titans punch at the same speed otherwise.

Comment: What's the knockback number?  A distance?  Hammer units (16 per foot)?

Comment: @NickT - it's an internal measure of the game distance, I think you can compare it to sprint speed stats and the range on explosions in the source link.

Comment: Further, what do you mean "it gets knocked back further"--the opposing Titan?  It doesn't seem like the puncher gets moved appreciably...

Comment: The titan that's punched goes further. Punching a stryder pushes it further away than punching an Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have the actual damage numbers (they aren't ingame anywhere and unless the developers said something on the forums we don't know) I do know from experience how much they generally deal with Big Punch.

(the following is with big punch... as I never drop a titan without it)

- Ogre does the most damage, but punches really slow with a long recovery. Completely eliminates shields in a single punch and can take down other titans in 3-5 punches (depending on the chassis and if you are shooting at them as well)
- Atlas does mid damage, mid speed, and mid recovery. It can mostly take down shields (very little left) and takes noticeable more punches to take down other titans.
- Stryder does piddly punches but punches really fast and has a quick recovery time. A single punch will take down full shields to about half. Also not recommended to take down other titans with punches only.

Comment: This is incorrect. The Stryder does more damage than the Atlas, see my answer.